# is it possible to migrate a plain react-app into next-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is it possible to change/convert a plain react app into next app?

I have a project created with create react app but things have changed and now I want to switch the project into next app

maybe there's a possible way to do that? or should i start over from scratch to build my next app project?

I've been trying to research on how to migrate the project, but didn't found the solutions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to answer this question without seeing the actual project and dependencies you use, but here's a few considerations:

- You'll need to convert your current routing solution to the one Next.js uses. Their routing is determined by the file system structure, rather than in code (like react-router). For more information, see their docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/introduction
- Ensure all your components and dependencies can render on the server, this may require moving behaviour that uses browser APIs into `useEffect` hooks (like window or document properties).
- Move your hosting and building to something that supports Next.js configurations. There are a few including Vercel, Netlify & AWS.

Also check out their own migration guides that cover how to convert configurations to Next.js: https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/incremental-adoption

In short, it really depends on what you're currently using and will require manual conversion your code. I hope this was still helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's definitely possible to port / migrate your React app to Next.js. I have actually migrated two of my React apps by now to Next.js and while in general its relatively straight forward there are definitely some gotchas here and there.

Some initial things to consider:

- Next.js uses [File-system based](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts) routing so your project folder structure will need to mimic the routing you want (dynamic routes are also supported)
- Any component that needs access to browser APIs like fetch() or localstorage() will need to be [rendered client-side](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components), meaning you'll need to add the `'use client'` directive to the top of the source file.
- If your React app uses [global imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling) note that Next.js only allows global imports for source under the `/app` directory, so you may need to refactor or move files around again.

I actually thought this would be a common topic so even wrote a blog about this to help others with the migration and try to cover some key steps, hope it helps:

**"Steps for converting your React projects to Next.js, problems you may encounter, plus some tips and tricks."**

https://ergin-d.com/blog/convert-react-to-nextjs (Jan 2024)